# PayPal How to Update Recurring Profile without forcing user re-enter their credit card detail?

Tags: paypal, updates, credit-card, required, recurring

My site is using the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile NVP API to deal with recurring payment.
I want to provide our customer the ability to update his subscription without re-entering his credit card info again. But I could'nt resolve the problem because Paypal would reject my API call if I did not pass the credit card number. I thought that there just need the profile id for enough but it did not.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

I followed that link and I saw Paypal required the param ACCT. 
I just think about other direction, that is storing the credit card as this guide

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/

But I have no idea how to pass the token into the NVP API UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile.
Did any one have experienced with same problem? Any help is appreciated.